# 'Can't open microphone' in Google app, can't make calls s5

Tags: microphone

**The problem**
I factory reset my s5 to sell, but now, after a week or so, I cannot make calls, use the Google app (pictured) or hear any sound from the speakers other than a very light static. When trying to make a call, pressing the call button clears the text field and nothing further happens.
**What I've tried**
I've restarted the phone, reset the phone, changed the Google voice settings, and wiped the cache.
**Device information**
Samsung G900V galaxy s5
Android version 5.0
Anker nfc battery

[image]
<sup>Click to enlarge image</sup>

Comment: It may be difficult to pinpoint the solution as the problem is not reproducible. Since there is an update available, to Marshmallow, why not update the phone to see if it fixes the problem. In any case, you are planning to sell the phone so updation- won't hurt

Comment: I think something went wrong when you factory reseted your device and messed up your phone's drivers. You should make a clean install -> flash an official ROM (get one from SamFirmare) with Odin/Heimdall. Android 6 also available to your device, give it a try.

Comment: [This has a bunch of reasons](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/websearch/1otPCC0fjJU)  that you can try to fix amongst different phones with same problem. Free common things 1. Disable S voice, it doesn't seem to get along with Google 2. Turn off *accessibility* for all apps restart device, if that didn't work, turn on ( sounds contrary, but it worked both ways) 3.Reset again and do not install updates for Google app ( turn off auto update).. It's confusing, I agree but a specific solution didn't seem to work for all. Cheers

Comment: 1.) Go to Settings-->Apps-->Google App
2.) Go to Permission manager
3.) Provide 'accept' option for 'Record audio'
from [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/WfBHXD_N6SI) also try disabling [S voice](http://phandroid.com/how-to-disable-s-voice-on-galaxy-s5/)// check if the problem repeats while in [safe mode](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-28456)- if it does you will have to go through all apps that have `microphone` access and disable or deny that